# Favoriting/bookmarking some documentation pages for quick access

Tags: documentation

Owing to the sheer size, it becomes quite hard to find an example code/explanation that one may have stumbled upon before, following hours of search through the depths of the documentation pages.

Is there a way to be able to favorite some documentation pages corresponding to Wolfram language functions/guides/tutorials/packages for quick and easy access later on?

Comment: You could store away the content of the search bar at the top of the help window.

Comment: yeah that is certainly possible, but I was hoping to see more efficient ways

Comment: You can create a Notebook with hyperlinks to your favorite Documentation pages (or even paragraphs on that pages).

Comment: I find it easier to maintain a list of bookmarks to the online documentation instead. Whenever I find something of interest, I look it up on the online version of the docs and save that bookmark in an organized list I have been maintaining in my browser, which has the advantage of being shared across all my devices as well.

Comment: At the top of the documentation page is a `URL` pull-down menu. Select `Go to web URL` then bookmark the web documentation page. On a web tutorial page, for a subsection of interest, click on the subsection link before bookmarking, then the bookmark will return to that subsection.